# multiple maximums in a list python

Tags: python, list, max, minimum

Hey so being the NEWBY I am I was wondering how I could find multiple maximums (i.e. there is more than one maximum or item of the same length) and minimums(same situ as maximums) from a list. I've tried using the `max` function but yet it prints only one item, same with `min`. It is to be done for length of the string in the list (e.g. using`len`)!

this is the code i had so far

```
    def choice4(filelist):
       try:
           c4longest=max(filelist,key=len)
           print(c4longest,"is the longest item in the list")
```

Comment: The builtin will only give you the first maximum.  If you want to return all of the maxima, you'll need to roll your own function for that (It should be pretty easy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
def choice4(filelist):
    mymax = max(map(len,filelist))
    return [a for a in filelist if len(a)==mymax]

a = ['joe','andy','mark','steve']
a.extend(a)
print choice4(a)
```

Comment: Let me know if you would like a revision on my posting to better serve your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use sorting instead:

```
maxed = sorted(inputlist, key=lambda i: len(i), reverse=True)
allmax = list(takewhile(lambda e: len(e) == len(maxed[0]), maxed))
```

which takes `O(n log n)` time for the sort; but it's easy and short as the longest elements are all at the start for easy picking.

For a `O(n)` solution use a loop:

```
maxlist = []
maxlen = 0
for el in inputlist:
    l = len(el)
    if l > maxlen:
       maxlist = [el]
       maxlen = l
    elif l == maxlen:
       maxlist.append(el)
```

where `maxlist` is built and replaced as needed to hold only the longest elements:

```
>>> inputlist = 'And so we give a demo once more'.split()
>>> maxlist = []
>>> maxlen = 0
>>> for el in inputlist:
...     l = len(el)
...     if l > maxlen:
...        maxlist = [el]
...        maxlen = l
...     elif l == maxlen:
...        maxlist.append(el)
... 
>>> maxlist
['give', 'demo', 'once', 'more']
```

Comment: This makes me cringe a bit from an algorithmic standpoint -- Why use an O(nlogn) algorithm when you only need to have O(n)?  -- That said, for moderate sized lists, this is quick, easy and effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: l = 'Is that what you mean'.split()

In [2]: [word for word in l if len(word) == max(map(len, l))]
Out[2]: ['that', 'what', 'mean']
```

Comment: But the O(n**2) could easily be cut down to O(n) by computing the max only once ... (after all, the result will be the same every time)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, yeah, but yours is `O(n log n)`, and it really can be done in one loop. But meh.

Answer (score 0):

use collections.Counter

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter({k:v for k,v in enumerate(L)})
print d.most_common(5)  # to get top 5
```